# Can I use spring boot to override a jdbc directory of legacy generated code?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I've got a set of code generated functions created from a proprietary application, they are in old school plain java form.

The generated code includes a direct jdbc connection, so I'm trying to get the ability to set the sqlite database path set from a spring boot cli app that executes the old school functions.

Can this be somehow be done? How should I approach this? I have no modern Java experience, only the painful process of old school Java SE. How would an experienced developer approach this situation?

The only ability I have to modify the old school generation, is setting jdbc connection details.

Comment: Could you please add a short example of generated code with an emphasis on jdbc connection part?

Comment: Yea, will add those details.